# Not quite a Correlation or Covariance Matrix, not quite a Contingency Table - what is this matrix and what can it tell me?

Tags: covariance-matrix, contingency-tables

I don't have a formal background in statistics, but I do have a PhD concerning factor anaysis which was awarded by a physics department.

I am looking to do some affinity analysis of spares demand. I have data on repairs undertaken to equipment over a number of years, each repair requiring zero or more spares to complete. I therefore have data on which spares are used to repair which equipment, and which spares are used together to complete repairs and in what quantities.

For each type of  equipment (or indeed all equipment), I am therefore able to construct a square matrix, the rows and columns of which represent spares, and the elements of which represent associations between spares, i.e. when spares are used together to complete a repair. Row A, column B will show the fraction of repairs when spare A is used that also used spare B. So, although the diagonal of the matrix will contain all '1's, it will not be symmetric. Careful ordering of the attribution of spares to rows and columns will probably make it a band matrix, however.

My questions are:

1. What is the name of this type of matrix, if indeed it has one?
2. Can some sort of eigen or other analysis of this type of matrix help me in the context of affinity analysis? My work with factor analysis and PCA is leading me in this direction, but I am not sure if I am barking up completely the wrong tree.

Comment: You could interpret this as an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix), corresponding to a weighted directed graph. Many "spectral" style algorithms then use the corresponding [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily turn this into a correlation matrix. You have a random variable $\vec S$ representing the vector of spares, each entry of which is 0 if the spare is being used for the given repair and 1 if it is. Your matrix is $M_{ij} = E[S_i S_j]$, so that the $i$-th row and $j$-th column represents the fraction of repairs where the two spares are used jointly, as you've stated. The covariance matrix would be $C_{ij} = E[S_i S_j] - E[S_i] E[S_j]$. Since $S_i^2 = S_i$, $E[S_i] = M_{ii}$, and you should have all the information you need to calculate the covariance in usage rates:
$$
C_{ij} = M_{ij} - M_{ii} M_{jj}
$$

Comment: I think the matrix you describe above is subtly different from the one I describe in my question. Each element of my matrix is (for Row A, column B) = P(B|A), i.e. the probability that spare B will be used where spare A is being used. This is what makes the matrix non-symmetric, since P(B|A) != P(A|B). From what I can see, your $M_{ij}$ is symmetric.
    
Also, what is the E[...] operation please?

Comment: @MattWenham I did misunderstand what your matrix was, then. And I am using $E[...]$ as a shorthand for the mean.

Comment: Ah, expected value? Makes sense. However, from the point of view of the original question, I'm still at square one.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comment:

> You could interpret this as an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix), corresponding to a
>   weighted directed graph. Many "spectral" style algorithms then use the
>   corresponding [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix).

– GeoMatt22

For examples, see [this posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=laplac*+graph*+spec*+answers%3A1).